# why Segmentation fault error in this program in c?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, segmentation-fault

Why is dr  segmentation fault in this code?
Everything look correct here, syntax ... etc.The program is simple,just two sort content of two arrays into a third array; So I have taken two arrays `array1` and `array2`
and the third one is `array` in which sorting is to be done.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    int array1[10] = {1, 2, 4,5,7,8,45,21,78,25};
    int array2[5] = {3, 6, 9,15,17};
    int array[20];
    int i,j,temp;
    int l1 = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);
    int l2 = sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int);
    int l3 = l1+l3;

    for (i = 0;i < l1; i++) 
    {
        array[i]=array1[i];
    }
    for (i = 0;i < l2; i++) 
    {
        array[i+l1]=array2[i];
    }
    for (i = 0;i < (l1+l2); i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSorted array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<l3;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<l3;j++)
        {
            if(array[i] > array[j])
            {
                temp=array[i];
                array[i]=array[j];
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < l3; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Basic debugging technique: Add trace output. Check your assumptions. (In this case, on array indices.)

Comment: `int l3=l1+l3` on last declaration line could cause this

Comment: compile using something like `gcc -Wall -g yourSrc.c debug` and run through a debugger (`gdb debug` command, for example)

Answer (score 5):

Because *this* is not what you want:

```
int l3 = l1 + l3;
```

It will simply add the known `l1` to the arbitrary `l3`, giving you a slightly larger arbitrary value. Instead, it should be:

```
int l3 = l1 + l2;
```

---

The other, though relatively minor, problem you have is the efficiency of the algorithm, specifically the start and end conditions of the loops. The code:

```
for (i = 0; i < l3; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < l3; j++) {
```

has two problems. First, the `i` loop goes too far since we know that when it's at `l3 - 1`, there are *no* elements to the right. Secondly, the `j` loop starts at `i` and we *know* that `array[x] > array[x]` can never be true (`x` because `i == j`).

It would be better to use:

```
for (i = 0; i < l3 - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < l3; j++) {
```

to remove these inefficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

> // l3 will have garbage value which might be a greater than 20(max size of your array)
>
> int l3 = l1+l3;

When you are using this in the loops

```
for(i=0;i<l3;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<l3;j++)
    {
        if(array[i] > array[j])
        {
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0;i < l3; i++) 
{
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

l3 value may be more than 20 say 30 when accessing the 30th location of the array will lead to segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are exceeded the size of array

check this instruction: `int I3 = I1+I3` you should replace it by `int I3 = I1+I2`